# How to store props into a single state object

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that receives multiple props, I want to store all those props into a single object in state and exchange them by one, how would I do that?

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
class Stock extends Component {
    state={
    asteroid:{ i want to put all my props here as a single object}
          };
          
    render() {
            const nickel = this.props.chemPerDay[0];
            const iron = this.props.chemPerDay[1];
            const cobalt = this.props.chemPerDay[2];
            const water = this.props.chemPerDay[2];
            const nirtogen = this.props.chemPerDay[4];
            console.log(nickel, iron, cobalt, water, nirtogen, "NICKEL");
            console.log(this.props.chemPerDay, "stockprops?");
            return (
              <div>
                <p> remaing: {this.props.remainingMpct} %</p>
                <p> remaing: {this.props.remainingMassPerday} mass</p>
                <p> Yield: {this.props.asteroidYieldPerDay}</p>
                <p> nickel: {nickel} </p>
                <p> iron: {iron} </p>
                <p> cobalt: {cobalt} </p>
                <p> water: {water} </p>
              </div>
            );
     }
```

}
export default Stock;

These props are all the values I need every day, but I want to make a button increments by a day that updates the state for every day

How can I do this?

Comment: [Don't copy props to state](https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/06/07/you-probably-dont-need-derived-state.html#anti-pattern-unconditionally-copying-props-to-state). If you want to keep the data combined, you can pass a single **object** as prop.

Comment: ok, spread operator worked, all the props that i get are the values for a day, so the second day should be double the values and third day should be triple etc... how would i do that?

Comment: You can have one more variable in state, e.g. `days`, initialized with `0` and increment it by `1` after clicking the button: `this.setState(prevState => ({ days: prevState.days + 1 }))` and you multiply it when rendering e.g. `<div>{this.state.nickle * this.state.days}</div>`.

Comment: that did the trick!!! thank you!!

Answer (score 0):

As for the adding props to state - you can use spread operator like this:

```
state={
  asteroid:{ ...this.props },
  days: 1
}
```

If your state depends on days quantity, you can store the days quantity in you state also. Add the state like shown above with initial value 1. Then refactor your rendering part with elements which are need to be multiplied like this:

```
<p> Yield: {this.props.asteroid.asteroidYieldPerDay * this.props.days}</p>
```

Comment: all the props that i get are the values for a day, so the second day should be double the values and third day should be triple etc... how would i do that?

Comment: the values of an asteroid per day are  :   asteroid:{    yieldPerDay: 23, remainingMass:40000, chemicals:{ nickel: 25, iron: 34, cobalt: 45} }  i want the state to updaet x the day

Answer (score 0):

You could also set up the state like this:

```
this.state = {
  nickle: props.chemPerDay[0],
  iron: props.chemPerDay[1],
  cobalt: props.chemPerDay[2]
};
```

If you want to multiply those values when clicking a button, you need to create an `onClick` function to multiply the values in the state and then update the state.

https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bas-p1p6d?file=/src/App.js:132-255

Comment: i understand that i have to make an button that update state, but i don't  want to just update the chemicals but the entire object of asteroid, so also the yield ect, because the props i passed are all the data for one asteroid per day, so I want to know how to setState? this.setState({asteroid: asteroid x day}) i want to know how to do that.

Comment: In your Stock class, say your state is just an array like "state={asteroid: [1, 2, 3]}" where each number represents a certain property. If you're wanting to multiply the entire state/array, you're going to have to loop through each array element, multiply the element. Then update the state.

I updated the code: https://codesandbox.io/s/hopeful-bas-p1p6d?file=/src/App.js